# How to get sum of the rows of 3 tables

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables and I want to know with one query sum of row's number in 3 tables

I tried 2 different queries but it they give only the number of rows each table and I c'ant read with,

```
     return int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

the sum of rows of 3 tables.

I must read by reader and get the sum

Here are 2 queries I used:

```
    SELECT  (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   prodbiscuit WHERE status =2
        ) AS count1,
        (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   prodganache WHERE status =2
        ) AS count1,
        (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   prodmacaron
        ) AS count1
        FROM   dual
```

And the other query which give the same result:

```
       SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT nom) as rows FROM prodbiscuit WHERE status=2 

       UNION SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT nom) AS rows FROM prodganache WHERE status=2  

       UNION SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT nom) AS rows FROM prodmacaron
```

How to get real sum of rows of tree tables with one query?

Should I use absolutely reader ?

Answer (score 1):

http://searchoracle.techtarget.com/answer/Sum-of-two-table-row-counts-as-one-answer

```
 select ( select count(DISTINCT nom) from prodbiscuit WHERE status =2 )
 + ( select count(DISTINCT nom) from prodganache WHERE status =2 ) 
 + ( select count(DISTINCT nom) from prodmacaron) 
      as total_rows
```

Finally I've found it at given link

Answer (score 0):

I would create a variable then add each one to the variable.  When its done, the variable would have the result.  I'm coming up with this off the top of my head.  It sounded viable.